# How can i manage my dependencies?

Tags: php, object

i'm working on a likely a large PHP project where i have too many classes, and my problem appears when some classes depends on others, for example the error-handling class may depend on the security class, the user class may depend on the database class and so on...

```
$obj1 = new class1();
$obj2 = new class2($obj1);
$obj3 = new class3();
$obj4 = new class4($obj3 , $obj1);
etc...
```

hence my quesion comes in! what is the best way to manage dependancies ?

Comment: You might also be interested in [PHPXref](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Is this about autoloading the classes or about passing objects to other objects ?

Comment: Look into the Symfony Dependency Injection Container, it's quite useful.

Comment: @EvilThinker Without being disrespectful: In your case your major problem is bad architecture of the app.

Comment: deceze is right, what you need for the provided example is some kind of dependency injection (also called inversion of control). Another usefull topic would be dependency management (e.g. composer tries to solve this for php). And last but not least, you should indeed have another thought about your application architecture. Why does a class for error handling depend on a class for security?

Comment: he is using (constructor) dependency injection already: `$obj2 = new class2($obj1);`

Comment: paulsm4 Thanks , i'll check the link out. Panique May be your right , i'm working on the app for more than 1 year and it's getting larger , it's too hard to recode or reorganize the whole stuff  . deceze : i'll check this out thanks. @Ska : i do use Composer to use PHP libraries for different goals but i don't think it can solve my problem, and btw i just gave you an example with the security and the error classes !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try autoloading your classes.  That way if a class needs another class, it doesn't have to `require()` it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Example from the documentation:

```
<?php

function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');

// Or, using an anonymous function as of PHP 5.3.0
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});

?>
```

Comment: Autoloading solves the problem of including files, it does not solve the dependency graph problem.

Comment: @deceze but then the question if weirdly formulated. I was also thinking it's about autoloaders!

Comment: @deceze, I agree, but my read from his question is that this is at least part of the problem.  If that turns out not to be the case, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: well Brad , i think my problem can be solved this way if i didn't passed the objects through the contructors and i had to 'require' the classes and call objects inside other classes !